# Which of these statements are correct and will compile?

Tags: java, oop

I did some work on these two homework assignments and I need to know if my answers are correct.

> ```
> public abstract class Account {
>     public Account( ) { . . . }
> }
>
> public class BankAccount extends Account {
>      private double balance;      
>      public BankAccount (double amount) {
>          super( );
>          balance = amount;
>      }
>   }
>
> public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {
>        private String customerName;     
>        public CheckingAccount (String name, double amount) {
>            <Missing Statement>
>        }
>        . . .
>  }
> ```
>
> Question 1. Which of the following is an acceptable replacement for in CheckingAccount's constructor?
>
> I.
>
> ```
> balance = amount;
> customerName = name;
> ```
>
> II.
>
> ```
> super(amount);
> customerName = name;
> ```
>
> III. `super (name,amount);`
>
> Possible:
>
> I only
>   II only
>   I and II
>   II and III
>   I, II and III
>
> Question 2. Which of the following declarations are valid?
>
> I. `Account acct = new BankAccount(10.00);`
>   II. `CheckingAccount acct = new BankAccount (10.00);`
>   III. `BankAccount acct = new CheckingAccount("Amy", 10.00);`
>
> Possible:
>
> I and II
>   II and III
>   I and III
>   I, II, and III
>   None of the three

My answers:

1. II and III
2. I and II

What do you think are the answers for these questions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't CheckMyHomework.com. Please go through the [help] section to see just what this site is for.

Comment: I think you can reformulate your question by adding your reasons why you think your answers are good and then we may help you to find the right path or tell you if you're good

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I highly disagree with the close vote (at least reason). HW questions are fine here. He has given a problem, showed effort to solve it on his own, and asks what is the answer for it. Seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @amit: homework questions are fine, but not of this type. This is not a "here is a problem with my code" but rather, "please check my homework for errors" without even telling us if there are any errors. This is highly inappropriate for this site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If he'd replace "Check my answer" with "What do you think?" Would it be OK? (I believe so, and that's why we have editting priviliges)

Comment: @amit I still think this is not ok because OP should at least explain why he/she thinks his/her answers are right, otherwise we would be doing his/her homework (as you've done with your answer).

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:

Only II is correct. 

III is incorrect because the constructor `BankAccount(String,double)` is not defined. Note that `BankAccount` does not have any knowledge of existence of the `name` field which you want to populate.

Question 2:

I and III are correct

II is incorrect becasue you cannot assign a `BankingAccount` into a `CheckingAccount` variable. `BankAccount` is NOT a `CheckingAccount`. What will happen if you later try to access any of its methods, that are NOT defined in `BankAccount`?

III is correct because `CheckingAccount` is a `BankingAccount`.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for replying. I agree with every one of you, and next time, I'll reformulate my questions so that you guys can help me to the right path.